# SQL CASE when using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, case

I have a new column in a table which I need to now join tables on. Previously the table looked like this:

```
date        id            
05-18       abc       
05-18       abc        
05-18       cde        
05-18       gtf
```

Now, a new column has been introduced:

```
date        id              id_without_params   
05-18       abc      
05-18       abc      
05-18       cde      
05-18       gtf              
05-19       abc123626        abc
05-19       cde345634        cde
05-19       gtf437437        gtf
```

Previously I joined tables on `id` column, now this column has new values, starting `05-19` and I can no longer join on it because the values hold additional user parameters which I can't join on and new column `id_without_params` has been introduced which holds the value which has previously been used in `id` column.

I want to write a `JOIN` with a `CASE` which would join the table_a and table_b with the ide like this:

If id `id_without_params exists`, join on it, if not, join on `id`

Or maybe this could work as well:

If `id_without_params` is null then `id_without_params` = `id`, but I am unsure how would any of this fit in a `LEFT JOIN CASE`

The end goal is to join table_a and table_b on id_without_params if value exists, if not join it on id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches for this. The simplest one might be the use of `COALESCE` function.

The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null value in a list. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp

So, in your case you can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
ON COALESCE(table_a.id_without_params, table_a.id) = table_b.target_column;
```

The JOIN will be performed between `table_a.id_without_params` and `table_b.target_column` if `table_a.id_without_params` is not NULL.

Otherwise, the JOIN would be performed between `table_a.id` and `table_b.target_column`.

This should work for any kind of JOIN.

You can find more approaches here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/select-not-null-column-from-two-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you, do you have an idea of its efficiency in terms of memory?

Comment: No, I don't know how efficient is regarding memory.